# How do I view the full properties of a file in the Properties dialog box?

Tags: windows-10, window, resizing

I'm trying to look at the Properties of a Consolas font TTF file, but it cuts off the sentences midway (eg `File Description`/`License Description`) and I can't resize the Properties window by click-dragging the edges. Is there some way for me to resize the Properties window or otherwise view the entire details contained in the Properties window?

(I'm using Windows 10)

[image: screenshot of Properties window]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so a temporary solution I found for now is to just open up the ttf file in Notepad++ and search for the beginning of the Copyright text. The formatting is bad but at least it's better than nothing. If someone knows of a tool that can list the information neatly, please mention it in a separate answer.

[image: screenshot of notepad++ with full copyright info]